# In MVVM, whose job is it to decide the Navigation Flow? ViewModel or View?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack

In Android Context, should the decision point be inside the ViewModel something like in my ViewModel when a response is received:

```
if (response.isSuccess()) {
    nextScreenLiveData.value = GO_TO_NEXT_SCREEN
} else if(response.isNeedAnotherScreen()) {
    anotherScreenLiveData.value = ANOTHER_SCREEN
} else {
    backToBeforeScreen = BACK_TO_BEFORE_SCREEN
}
```

Then all these LiveDatas will be observed in the Activity/Fragment. Meaning one oberver for each LiveData.

Or is it better to just do something like this in my ViewModel:

```
liveData.value = response
```

then in my Activity/Fragment have the decision instead:

```
liveData.observe(this, Observer { response ->
   if (response.isSuccess()) {
        goToNextScreen()
    } else if(response.isNeedAnotherScreen()) {
        goToAnotherScreen()
    } else {
        goBack()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the latter approach is more clean and better.

Comment: I also do think so too.. Its just that I still wanna have second opinion and does it not violate that all logic must be inside the view model?

Comment: You can use MVVM-C, where C is coordinator(Router) and where you should write all the navigation code. If you want to avoid coordinator and strictly use MVVM, then the navigation should be done in the View.

Comment: Can you give me some example of what this C (Router is all about and how is it setup)?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones take a look at https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/shared/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/shared/result/Event.kt and https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/LaunchViewModel.kt and https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/LauncherActivity.kt

Comment: @Raghunandan is that a way to do the "Router"?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones its from the official io schedule app recently open sourced. so i would say yes.

Comment: Wow.. hmm.. I'll try t study it then.. have you been using the same pattern?

Comment: Base on what I understand from what the code you linked is, its simply a LiveData which checks whether the value set on it is already consumed which makes sense since if its for navigation, then you don't want to have double navigation (on rotation, on background then back to foreground). That sample does not show how to handle data passing. Do you have any idea how to do that?